# Wrapping IO-bound asynchronous methods in Task.Run

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

The following is quoted from [Using the Built-in Task-based Combinators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/consuming-the-task-based-asynchronous-pattern#combinators) section.

```
public async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = await Task.Run(async() =>
    {
        using(Bitmap bmp1 = await DownloadFirstImageAsync())
        using(Bitmap bmp2 = await DownloadSecondImageAsync())
        return Mashup(bmp1, bmp2);
    });
}
```

## Question

According to what I have read from other resources, IO-bound asynchronous methods should not be wrapped with `Task.Run` because "we don't need to spawn another thread just to wait an IO-bound operation to complete".

It seems the code above and the concept I read from the others are contradictory. Could you let me know which one is the correct one?

Comment: The examples in docs aren't always real-world. Notice the first example specifically calls out the compute-boundness of the operation. This example is doing `Download_some_ImageAsync` which results in a Bitmap so maybe it is supposed to be doing some cpu bound work of converting the response to a Bitmap. I personally would avoid `Task.Run`ing http calls.

Comment: `Task.Run` is because of  `return Mashup(bmp1, bmp2);`. Without that, you could simply `await` the already `async` `DownloadSomethingAsync()`. The framework provides async IO methods that you just `await`. Unless to add some other process (CPU-bound) in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is worth noting that the `Task.Run` drops your UI's `SynchronizationContext` while inside the actual `Run()` call. You could very well get rid of the global `Task.Run`, and simply `await First`, `await Second`, and then `Task.Run` only the `Mashup` part (if we keep the assumption that this method *is* CPU bound), but the subtle difference is that you would make a roundtrip to your UI thread's Dispatcher between each await (assuming they complete asynchronously, which they most likely do considering it's a download operation).

So in other words, the `Task.Run` here has the advantage of saving the UI thread from useless jumps. This is arguably completely negligible in this over-simplified example, but it is something to keep in mind in real-world scenarios. You would not want your precious UI thread to constantly be doing async book-keeping operations, however short-lived they may be. The general-purpose worker threadpool is perfect for doing those millions of thread-switches a second, and your UI thread can then spend time only on actual UI things.